# URL rewrite with IIRF makes dokuwiki slow

Tags: navigation, url-rewriting, slowdown, dokuwiki, iirf

**EDIT: the IIRF.ini code was not the problem in this case, the performance issues with dokuwiki were in fact permissions related, and the introduction of URL re-writing was not the cause of the issue.**

I've got a new instance of Dokuwiki (i.e. almost empty, not in use) which was running perfectly fine, before I integrated URL-rewriting using IIRF.

It now runs *significantly* more slowly - navigating between pages takes a number of seconds whereas before it was 'snappy' (immediate).

I followed the directions for implementing IIRF [here](http://www.dokuwiki.org/rewrite), which basically involves adding an "IIRF.ini" file to the site root, and updating the "conf/local.php" file as instructed on the site linked above (code copied from under the heading "Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter").

So to clarify, URL-rewriting is *working*; but it's caused significant slow-down in navigating the wiki.  I'd appreciate it if anyone could offer a suggestion for bringing it up to speed again!

This is the contents of my "IIRF.ini" file:

```
IterationLimit 1

# QSA is not supported, fix it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
RewriteRule (.*)\?(.*) $1&$2

RewriteRule ^/_media/(.*)             /lib/exe/fetch.php?media=$1   [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/_detail/(.*)            /lib/exe/detail.php?media=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/_export/([^/]+)/(.*)    /doku.php?do=export_$1&id=$2  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/$                       /doku.php                     [QSA,L]

# infinite redirect fix
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$                  /doku.php?id=$1               [QSA,L]

# end fix
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)                    /doku.php?id=$1               [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The ini file there is incorrect - at least the COMMENT is incorrect.  The comment says `# QSA is not supported, fix it`, but this is not correct for IIRF.  IIRF supports QSA.  You don't need that stanza in the IIRF file.  The ini code you got has some stale bits.

Comment: You may well be right Cheeso, I copied this file from the dokuwiki documentation so I wouldn't know if the comment was correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an an answer but some suggestions:

1. Do you know if it's a specific rule that's causing the problem or IIRF itself?  Comment out all the rukes and try just the following:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(*.) $1
   ```

   To test IIRF prformance then uncomment other rules.
2. Switch on tracing. Are the rules behaving as expected?
3. Use the `TestDriver` application to run your tests.
4. Try to run your tests in the context of the user your web server software uses.

My guess is that there is an access issue on a file or directory test.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer because you're right in the last thing you said, that it turned out to be an access/permissions related issue.  It seems dokuwiki needed more permissions when supporting URL re-writing than it did without it.